# How to sum amounts by Group By Roll Up

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, rollup

- i need to sum amounts with group by G and T but getting this error:

"Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'TEMP_BFTOPLAM.GIDERCESIDI_KODU' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'TEMP_BFTOPLAM.GCADI' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
"

- When i write the C column inside the roll up it run but i should do it without C. How can i do that?

```
SELECT  G,T,C
        ,T.AMOUNT
       ,FORMAT(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(ROUND([BUTCETUTAR],0) AS FLOAT),0)),'#,#') AS '2019 November B'
       ,FORMAT(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(ROUND([FIILITUTAR],0) AS FLOAT),0)),'#,#') AS '2019 November F'
       ,FORMAT(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(ROUND([FARK],0) AS FLOAT),0)),'#,#') AS '2019 November B-F'
       ,FORMAT(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(ROUND([BUTCETUTARTOPLAM],0) AS FLOAT),0)),'#,#')  AS '2019 November B Küm.'
       ,FORMAT(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(ROUND([FIILITUTARTOPLAM],0) AS FLOAT),0)),'#,#')  '2019 November F Küm.'
       ,FORMAT(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(ROUND([TOPLAMFARK],0) AS FLOAT),0)),'#,#')  AS '2019 November B-F Küm.'
       ,FORMAT(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(ROUND([BUTCEYILLIK],0) AS FLOAT),0)),'#,#')  AS '2019B' 

       FROM   TEMP_BFTOPLAM T
RIGHT JOIN  (
SELECT GYGD.GIDERYERIGRUBU_KODU,GYGD.GIDERYERI_KODU,GYG.ADI  GIDERYERIGRUBU_ADI
FROM [dbo].[UI_OZLGIDERYERIGRUBUDETAY] GYGD, [dbo].[UI_OZLGIDERYERIGRUBU] GYG
WHERE  GYG.KODU=GYGD.GIDERYERIGRUBU_KODU ) G on T.GIDERYERI_KODU= G.GIDERYERI_KODU 
WHERE (BUTCETUTAR<>0 OR FIILITUTAR<>0 OR BUTCETUTARTOPLAM<>0 OR  FIILITUTARTOPLAM <>0 )
GROUP BY 
ROLLUP(
G,T
   )
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: GROUP BY 
ROLLUP - is not valid you have to group by something..